# Django model filter by an empty string

Tags: python, django

I've got the following view:

```
def search_events(request):
    term = request.GET.get('term', '')
    adminDivision = request.GET.get('adminDivision', '')
    events = Event.objects.filter(event_name__icontains=term, city__admin1=adminDivision)
    data= serializers.serialize('json', events);
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

It can receive 2 parameters from the request, term and adminDivision, and then it makes a search on the DB.

The way it works now is that when one of them is empty, term or adminDivision, then I get no results, as all the objects has some value for those fields.

What I want is, if one or even both filters are empty, then don't apply that filter.

Example,
if I've got these objects:

- [event_name='foo', adminDivision='1']
- [event_name='bar', adminDivision='2']
- [event_name='foo bar', adminDivision='3']

With `term=foo` (no value for adminDivision) at the moment, I'am getting no results, but I would want it to return the first and the third.

With both values empty, I am also getting no results, and I'd like to have all them.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use forms to process data from GET and POST requests instead of accessing `request.GET` directly in your view.

Comment: Can you give more details or provide a link with examples? I am calling this method from an ajax request, so I am not sure how to use forms here. Anyway, I am starting with django, so any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting results because you are performing an `AND` query in your filter. Try like this:

```
def search_events(request):
    term = request.GET.get('term', '')
    adminDivision = request.GET.get('adminDivision', '')
    events = Event.objects.all()
    if term:
        events = events.filter(event_name__icontains=term)
    if adminDivision:
        events = events.filter(city__admin1=adminDivision)
    data= serializers.serialize('json', events);
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Or:

```
from django.db.models import Q

...
events = Event.objects.filter(Q(event_name__icontains=term)|Q(city__admin1=adminDivision))
...
```

Comment: Thanks, first option works as I wanted, second doesn't as if both element are present, it will return all object which contains one or the other.

Comment: Yes, your first option was an AND and my second option is an OR, that's why I wrote it second, maybe another person could find it helpful.